# Get resource value *without* using GetGlobalResourceObject

Tags: asp.net

I have an MVC web app that uses a custom folder & namespace for resource files.  I need to be able to pull late-bound values from my resource file, i.e. using the resource type and string.  I tried using:

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("ResourceClass", "SomeKey")
```

But that returns null.  When I move the resource to App_GlobalResources, that works, but cascades into other issues.  I tried working through those, but they seem to be deeper and more in number than going back to my original plan of just being able to read from the resource file in the custom folder.

In a nutshell, I'm trying to localize my xVal validation, both the error message, and in the case of a RegEx validator, the pattern.  I've got everything working, except for this one piece, where I'm trying to localize the pattern.  Since this isn't built into DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute, I need to fetch it myself, based on the resource type and name provided in the attribute.  Hence my dilemma.

Can I get to the resource value using some other method?  Or, must my resource file reside in the App_GlobalResources folder?  If the latter, then I will need to open another discussion for all my other issues -- or implement some cruder form of localization for the regex stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Jerad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution we came up with:

```
public static class ResourceHelper
{
    public static string GetString(Type resourceType, string resourceName)
    {
        return new ResourceManager(resourceType.FullName, resourceType.Assembly)
            .GetString(resourceName);
    }

    public static string GetString(Type resourceType, string resourceName, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new ResourceManager(resourceType.FullName, resourceType.Assembly)
            .GetString(resourceName, culture);
    }

    public static object GetObject(Type resourceType, string resourceName)
    {
        return new ResourceManager(resourceType.FullName, resourceType.Assembly)
            .GetObject(resourceName);
    }

    public static object GetObject(Type resourceType, string resourceName, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new ResourceManager(resourceType.FullName, resourceType.Assembly)
            .GetObject(resourceName, culture);
    }
}
```